# <p>...</p> showing full stop before text

Tags: html, css

I created an unslider http://unslider.com/ using this HTML code

```
<div class="un-slider" dir="rtl">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <blockquote class="testimonial">
                            <p>Hello world i m arbaz mateen. like a little programmer.</p>
                        </blockquote>   
                        <div class="testimonial-arrow-down">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="testimonial-author">
                            <img src="" border="0" width="50" height="50">
                            <p><strong>Huzaifa Khalid</strong><br><span>BSCS Student at Iqra University</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; display: block;">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <blockquote class="testimonial">
                            <p>MeriTaleem helped me find the right information at the right time. I was looking for admission updates and wanted to know the process of how to apply for admissions.</p>
                        </blockquote>   
                        <div class="testimonial-arrow-down">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="testimonial-author">
                            <img src="" border="0" width="50" height="50">
                            <p><strong>Huzaifa Khalid</strong><br><span>BSCS Student at Iqra University</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

and I get the this result

[image]

paragraph looks like this

CSS

```
blockquote.testimonial {
background: rgba(177,227,172,0.9); 
color: #000;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 1.2em;
line-height: 1.3;
width: 80%;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 0;
margin: auto;
padding: 10px 50px;
position: relative;
display: block;
}

blockquote.testimonial p {
margin: 15px;
width: 90%;
padding: 20px 50px 20px 20px;
}

blockquote.testimonial:before {
color: #000;
content: "\201C";
font-size: 80px;
font-style: normal;
padding-right: 15px;
float: left;
}

blockquote.testimonial:after {
content: "\201D";
color: #000;
font-size: 80px;
font-style: normal;
float: right;
margin-top: -60px;
}
```

I don't know what the problem is with `<p>` tag.

Comment: Please consider adding your code to jsfiddle.net

Comment: Could be a problem with ltr vs rtl formatting … but to know more, we’d need to see a full example.

Comment: What is your problem? What is the desired solution?

Comment: @CBroe, check my answer and fiddle. His solution adds the **.** from UL list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appear as that because in your html `dir="rtl"` change it to `ltr` or just delete it

Comment: Actually, arabs write from right to left. Also, from what I see, that dot is from his UL item.

Comment: what you mean by UL ?

Comment: Judging by what was highlighted in author's screenshot, he means dot at the beginning of the sentence, not the one from `<ul>`.

Comment: @Microsmsm: Also, only English quotations should be ltr, rest should remain rtl, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your document have right to left text orientation and this is why there is dot in the beginning of the sentence. Your quotations are however in English and therefore should have left to right text orientation.

To achieve this add parameter `dir="ltr"` to both `<blockquote>`s.